# get-event log the handle is invalid

Tags: powershell

I Use the below command for read Event log:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName 'Operations Manager'
```

but the system return the below error :

```
 get-eventlog :the handle is invalid
```

why?and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What version of Windows and PowerShell?

Comment: windows is 2012 and powershell is 3

Comment: Is that log present when you open up Event Viewer? Also what happen what you do a Get-EventLog -LogName * ?